# Array in Object passed by value?

Tags: php, arrays

Maybe I am overlooking something, but I stumbled across this:

```
$employees = new stdClass();

$employee_id = 5;
$employee = array();
$employee["id"] = $employee_id;
$employee["name"] = "John;

$employees->$employee_id = $employee;
```

Now I want to change the employee Name:

```
$employee = $employees->$employee_id;
$employee["name"] = "Tom";
```

Now I have two problems:

1. The employee object seems not to be passed by reference, because the employee within the employees is still named John.
2. How would I retrieve the employee name?
   echo {$employee->$employee_id}["name"];
   does not work

Thanks for the help,

Martin

Comment: Why are you using $employees->$employee_id and not $employees->employee_id ?

Comment: 1.) see comment to answer from Emil.
2.) Why is it stupid code? Of course the employee name will not get changed immediately, but later on in a while loop when mysql data is read out. What would you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

1) PHP does rarely pass by reference. If you want to force a pass by reference, use the =& operator:

```
$employees->$employee_id =& $employee;
```

Read more here:
http://php.net/references

2) To use `$employees->$employee_id` in the first place is rather ugly, but here is a possible solution:

```
$current_employee =& $employee->$employee_id;
echo $current_employee['name'];
```

Comment: ad 1) ok. But actually Problem 1) is solved when I solve Problem 2, cause then I can assign it directly.

ad 2) Why is this rather ugly? I can not use an associative array, cause when it is send to the Frontend (ZendAMF) the keys do not get maintained, so I need to use an object. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra $ that should not be there.

```
//$employees->$employee_id = $employee;     Wrong
$employees->employee_id = $employee;
```

With the dollar, php uses the value of var. eg...

```
$name = "car";
$obj->car = 5;
$obj->$name = 10;

echo $obj->car;  // outputs 10
```

Comment: That confused me as well..  he basically has a class member named "5". :P

Comment: It apparently is since he did it twice, but I'm pretty sure he doesn't realize what the extra dollar sign does..

Comment: thx for the comments. please read the comment I made above. Yes I made it on purpose, for serializing the data properly, as ZendAMF does not treat Associative Arrays with numeric indices. They are not maintained after they are sent over the wire.